# convert xml to html using php

Tags: php, html, xml, xmltextreader, xslt

I want to convert xml data into html. Below is sample xml data and I want to get/convert it in html format.

```
<content type="html">
  <paragraph id="1291266887">
      <div class="red">
        <span id="main_post_id">
          <p>ten post przedstawia jak wys&#x142;a&#x107;  znacznik&#xF3;w w ust <strong>Ling</strong> -  xyz</p>
          <p>tags znane jako <span class="translation_section  section_2">bezpieczne</span>, b&#x119;d&#x105;  traktowane jako sekcje pkt</p>
          <p>innych materia&#x142;&#xF3;w dziel&#x105;  si&#x119; na <em>literach</em></p>
        </span>
      </div>
  </paragraph>
</content>
```

i.e. I want to get all the html code contained between `<paragraph id="..."></paragraph>`. I want to do it using php. When I convert it in array using php, it gives all data in array of div, p, span. But I want whole html contained in `<paragraph>..</paragraph>` tag in a single array.

Please help needed here. Let me know best ways for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to use xslt in PHP. If you got the xml in file "data.xml" and the xslt-script in "script.xsl" this is all to do:

```
<?php  
$proc=new XsltProcessor;  
$proc->importStylesheet(DOMDocument::load("data.xsl"));  
echo $proc->transformToXML(DOMDocument::load("script.xml"));  
?>
```

A simple xslt-script could look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">  
 <xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>  
  <xsl:template match="/">  
   <html>  
    <head>  
    </head>  
    <body>  
     <xsl:copy-of select="//paragraph"/>  
    </body>  
   </html>  
  </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Write a XSLT stylesheet to convert it, and the **xslt** extension to apply it to the XML.

Comment: I want to do it using php. When I convert it in array using php, it gives all data in array of div, p, span. But I want whole html contained in <paragraph>..</paragraph> tag in a single array.

Comment: Then you can't process it as XML, since processing it as XML will cause that.

Comment: I have just posted some part of xml data, not whole xml here. I am have converted it to array but not getting data contained in <paragraph>..</paragraph> in a single array or array key.

Answer (score 1):

> After running the following code in the browser save page , so the
>   file is created in two stages

```
<?php
$xml=simplexml_load_file("My_Xml.xml");
print_r($xml);
?>
```